# How to avoid gaps using Isotope with Masonry layout sortby random

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-isotope, jquery-masonry, masonry

I am using Isotope with Masonry layout and I noticed that sometimes leave the gaps between a box and the other (also if there is space to fit the other box).
but sometimes, if I refresh the page, it is ok and it fill all the gaps. (for this reason I don't think it is a problem of css)
I use fluid dimensions for the items and I have the sortBy: random mode.

I found that there is another script isotope-perfectmasonry, but it seems that works only with the old version of masonry (v1)

this is my code

```
var $grid = $('.grid').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // init Isotope after all images have loaded
   $('.grid').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.grid-item',
    layoutMode: 'masonry',
    sortBy : 'random',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
      gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
    }
  });
});
```

Is it possible fill all the gaps or it is impossible because it is random?
any idea how can i trigger a relayout if there are some gaps?

Comment: A jsfiddle or a link would be helpful.

Comment: thanks @Macsupport for your response, here there is a codepen http://codepen.io/mp1985/full/epQJQL/ if you open the page in "full page" mode you can see this strange behavior.
You can try to refresh the page and you can notice that sometimes there are gaps.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid gaps, you should you use the [packery](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html) layout mode of Isotope.

Here is a [codepen](http://codepen.io/tovly/pen/mVdXqm) demonstrating this.

The only differences are that the external javascript file for the packery layout is added (https://rawgit.com/metafizzy/isotope-packery/master/packery-mode.pkgd.min.js) and that the Isotope code is altered to what is below.

```
$('.grid').isotope({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  layoutMode: 'packery',
  sortBy: 'random',
  percentPosition: true,
  packery: {
    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
    gutter: '.gutter-sizer'
  }
});
```